# Build failed running Ionic cordova build android

Tags: node.js, android-studio, gradle, ionic3

Starting a new project with Ionic 3 and Android studio, the ionic run androisd command run but each time I tried to build I have got the following error message, seems like an error with `gradle`:

```
BUILD FAILED in 1s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\ecantero\Documents\Workspace\Ionic_project\charlotte\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
(node:2192) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2192) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.|
```

If anyone could help I am stock on thazt issue since two days..thanks in advance

Comment: [duplicate ] Possible solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49720788/error-to-compile-ionic-3-with-cordova-cordova-node-modules-cordova-common-src-s?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa